# java loop break with if statement?

Tags: java

while trying to do some exercises to learn java i wrote a simple program to calculate the count of worked hours and give the deserved salary.

```
package horulycalc;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HorulyCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner param = new Scanner(System.in);
        String [] titles  = {"Developer","Designer","Data Entry","Manager","CEO"};
        System.out.println("Hello and welcome to Job Counter");
        System.out.println("Please enter you Job Title");
        String title = param.nextLine();
        while(!Arrays.asList(titles).contains(title)){
            System.out.println("Please enter valid Job Title"); 
            title = param.nextLine();
            if(Arrays.asList(titles).contains(title)){
                System.out.println("Please enter your Hours for this week :");
                String count = param.nextLine();
                System.out.printf("Your Salary is : $ %f",HoursMath(HourRate(title),Integer.parseInt(count)));
                break ;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int HourRate(String jobTitle){
        int rate = 0;
        switch(jobTitle){
            case "Developer":
                rate = 10 ;
                break;
            case "Designer":
                rate = 8 ;
                break ;
            case "Data Entry":
                rate = 6;
                break ;
            case "Manager":
                rate = 15 ;
                break;
            case "CEO":
                rate = 36;
                break ;
        }
        return rate ;
    }

    public static float HoursMath(int rate ,int count){
        float total ;
        total = rate * count ;
        return total ;
    }
}
```

the program run fine if i added a wrong Job title for the first time i mean an input which is not included within the job titles array.

when i enter a valid Job Title in the first time for example "CEO" the program break and netbeans how it as its finished

Comment: I suggest you talk to the person who wrote it and ask them why they did that. ;)  If you want the hours calculation after a valid title is entered, put it after the loop.

Comment: @PeterLawrey should i talk to myself ?

Comment: @Dr.Neo - *talking to yourself* usually helps.. :).

Comment: Yes, ;)  You can move the `if` statement outside the loop and simplify the code. i.e. you want to calculate the hours after you have a valid title, I assume, so put that after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your while loop already tests for valid titles, you shouldn't test it inside the loop too.

This is simpler :

```
while(!Arrays.asList(titles).contains(title)){
    System.out.println("Please enter valid Job Title"); 
    title = param.nextLine();
}
System.out.println("Please enter your Hours for this week :");
String count = param.nextLine();
System.out.printf("Your Salary is : $ %f",HoursMath(HourRate(title),Integer.parseInt(count)));
```

You don't have to break from the loop this way. Once you are out of the loop, you know you have a valid title.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are not doing anything when the user first enters a valid value (which is in your array..)

```
    System.out.println("Please enter you Job Title");
    String title = param.nextLine(); // read title..
    while(!Arrays.asList(titles).contains(title)){ // while title is not present in array.
     }
 // nothing here--> what if title is present in the array / list?
  //So,Put this code here :. The below lines of code will be executed only hen you have a valid entry.
    System.out.println("Please enter your Hours for this week :");
    String count = param.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Your Salary is : $ %f",HoursMath(HourRate(title),Integer.parseInt(count)));
            break
```

Comment: His code does actually work. I think the problem is that it breaks after a single iteration with a "correct" job title input. Possibly I'm not understanding his question. But running the code with "CEO" prints `"Your Salary is : $ 360.000000"`.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers - No. he is using a *while* loop. So, if he enters "CEO" or any *valid* entry for the first time, the while will not be executed.

Comment: oops my bad, I first entered an invalid entry :-) he should just put his calculation logic after the while.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers - ya.. putting his calculation logic outside the while will help..